# Generation of a formula to map onto response surface analysis values/predict its maximum

Tags: surfaces

I'm new to StackExchange, so sorry if I don't format this question amazingly. I'm currently performing research on how the use of different proteins in a cell scaffold can change how well the scaffold promotes cell proliferation. Here's my setup:

X: Different values of Protein 1

Y: Different values of Protein 2

Z: Cell Proliferation results

I have 5 values for each protein that I'm varying. Thus, I get a total of 25 distinct pairs that I tested for cell proliferation. I've been able to graph the data (done via Origin) and find conclusions based on the trends, but I also wanted to estimate the most optimal pairing that would result in the highest amount of cell proliferation. I wanted to create a formula for the data, which would allow me to do so. I've been trying to work on it, but I'm not sure where to begin. I was wondering if anyone had experience doing this, and if they could offer some tips? Thank you very much.

Comment: You may also find a good - or better - response on Cross-Validated

Comment: Thanks @FShrike !